# Sending to a Salesforce Report Data Extension and Personalization String doesn't show fields from Report

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We created a Report in Salesforce with a field Account Owner (on the report). When I send to the report the Data Extension created doesn't have the fields from the Report and the Email doesn't render the Personalization string.

How do you add data from a Salesforce Report to an Email in Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the usual default attributes, only fields that have been configured as part of [Field Mapping](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/setting_up_the_connector/map_attribute_fields/) will be added to the Data Extension at send time (thus allowing the personalization strings to render).

Comment: I was afraid of that. Seems sort of confusing that you can create a Report with a bunch of fields that aren't accessible. :-(

Comment: Yes all report fields by default would be ideal. If you don't mind an extra step and a slightly buggy interface, you can always import the report and send to that resulting Data Extension.

Comment: That's what we were trying to avoid, but that's what we ended up doing. Thanks.